# Usecase Diagrams with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to generate usecase diagrams automatically from given actors and usecases when the user clicks a button. I am using Ruby on Rails on Netbeans IDE. Is there any plugin/gem or any other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Download NetBeans 6.7.1, then download the UML addon. Later versions of NetBeans does not support UML.